# Problem integrating Terminality with sublime text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I installed Terminality (https://github.com/spywhere/Terminality) using package control in sublime text 3 on macOS. In it's github page, it's showing that Terminality can work interactively like terminal. But, when I run a c program, it's taking all the input once and printing all the output once (like it works in competitive programming environments like Hackerrank or Codechef). It's working perfectly fine for python. Can anyone help me tweaking it so that it works interactively for C also? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like that package is no longer maintained by the author. It may still be possible to get it working, but if the idea is to run interactive executables in Sublime you may want to check out [Terminus](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Terminus) instead.

Comment: But with Terminus, as it is just an integrated terminal, we've to compile and execute the program manually everytime. I need something that can compile and execute the program with a shortcut (key binding). The way any IDE would basically do.

Comment: Well, your build system can compile and run a program all in one shot, if you want (the `C Single File` build that ships with Sublime can do this, for example). Essentially when you press `Ctrl+B`, the build will open the terminal, compile the program in it, then run it for you. Is that what this package is supposed to help with?

Comment: No. Actually, the build system is not able to read input from STDIN. I want an interactive input output mechanism, just like we get when we run program from terminal.

Comment: Standard build systems are not interactive because the command they execute can't do it. Terminus can be used as a replacement in this case to run an interactive build, as seen [here](https://youtu.be/mV0ghkMwTQc?t=660).